# How do I fetch just the beginning of a Web page with LWP?

Tags: perl, lwp

Does anyone know the best way to fetch just 50% of the Web page on a GET or POST request? The Web page I fetch takes me 10, 20 seconds to completely load, and I only need to filter just a few lines from the beginning of the page.

Answer (score 8):

```
use 5.010;
use strictures;
use LWP::UserAgent qw();

my $content;
LWP::UserAgent->new->get(
    $url,
    ':content_cb' => sub {
        my ($chunk, $res) = @_;
        state $length = $res->header('Content-Length');
        $content .= $chunk;
        die if length($content) / $length > 0.5;
    },
);
```

Comment: use strictures; ?  You mean 'strict', or...?

Comment: Don't use `strictures`. It's an entire CPAN dependency to save one line of code.

Comment: Do use strictures: who can install LWP can install that module, too, with negligible additional expense. It's just one dependency to save an entire line of code, **times** the 27 occasions I've used it on SO alone.

Comment: @daxim, what if you wanted to max it out at one megabyte? Then how would the code change? I tried changing the bottom part to "die if length($content) == 1", but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: `length($content) >= 1024 ** 2`

Comment: But isn't 1024 bytes a kilobyte? Doesn't length return the size in bytes? Sorry, but could you explain it to me?

Comment: @ikegami thank you for the link to the strictures module on CPAN.

Answer (score 3):

If the web site in question suppplies the `Content-Length` header you can just ask how much data is going to be sent and request only half of it.

This code demonstrates.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $url = 'http://website.test';

my $resp = $ua->head($url);
my $half = $resp->header('Content-Length') / 2;

$resp = $ua->get($url, Range => "bytes=1-$half");
my $content = $resp->content;
```

Comment: I tried this code out and it just gives me the entire page. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: [HTTP spec §14.35.2](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35.2): "A server MAY ignore the Range header." Dynamic responses rarely implement HTTP ranges.

Answer (score 2):

If the web application needs a long time to render the page you will usually have no possibility to accellerate the process by fetching 'half' of the page.

The page will be delivered after all the database queries and the actual rendering is done. And those are likely the reason for the long delays.