# LWP set max_size but still get content

Tags: perl, www-mechanize, lwp, lwp-useragent, max-size

I am using LWP to get the content from some sites and whenever the page size is larger than one megabyte, I would like LWP to stop downloading the page. This is accomplished with this code:

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->max_size(1024);
```

And it works fine. The only problem is that even when the page is over 1mb, I would still like to be able to get the content of what it has downloaded so far. However, whenever I do this (the traditional way to get content with LWP when there are no errors):

```
$ua->content;
```

It seems to not be the actual page's content but a bunch of nonsense. Does anyone know of a way to set max_size and still get whatever was downloaded before it hit the limit with LWP or even WWW::Mechanize? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Nine Perl-tagged questions earlier than yours there's this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10984127/716443, which produced excellent answers (http://stackoverflow.com/a/10984506/716443 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/10988170/716443) that should give you everything you need.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. Voted to close as duplicate question.