# perl WWW::Mechanize set max size and still get content

Tags: perl, www-mechanize, lwp-useragent, max-size

So I'm using WWW::Mechanize to get the content of pages, and I'd like to set a max size. Additionally, if the max size is hit I'd like to get the content that has been gotten up until this point. I know that in LWP you can do it like this:

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->max_size(1024);
$ua->get($url);
```

And now at this point even if 1024 bytes has been reached, `$ua->content` will still hold readable content that it had gotten up until that point. WWW::Mechanize is a subclass of LWP, so you can set it up basically the exact same way:

```
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new;
$mech->max_size(1024);
$mech->get($url);
```

And then you would think that since WWW::Mechanize is a subclass of LWP::UserAgent, `$mech->content` would hold the content that was retrieved until the size reached 1024 bytes. However, whenever I run this and reach the max size I get content from my WWW::Mechanize object that looks like this:

```
?|???-???+"?O<?p}?,?ܙmW ?`E??\\ސ???ѧ??U{3???
```

Does anyone know how I can get WWW::Mechanize to actually output something readable like its superclass LWP::UserAgent does? I like some of the extras that WWW::Mechanize provides, so I'd like to be able to keep using that if all possible rather than having to switch to LWP just for this. Thanks!

Comment: Are you reading gzip-compressed input or allowing the server to send compressed input?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10989684/lwp-set-max-size-but-still-get-content ?

Comment: it's not a duplicate because this is asking how to do it with WWW::Mechanize.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's `$mech->response->decoded_content`