# Perl Tool to read file located remotely before downloading through WGET

Tags: perl, wget

Suppose there is a text file link in a webpage. Now I can use HTML builder to parse the page, extract that link, and download that file into a directory of my choice through WGET. But is it possible to do a check on the file prior to downloading it? I mean, like checking the first 6 letters to find whether it matches the sequence `cooler`, and if it does, only then download it?

Comment: Define "cooler".  Less molecular kinetic activity?  Subjectively esthetically more pleasing?

Comment: What? I just gave it by way of an example, I just want to match some predefined text to see whether it is there at the starting of he file!

Comment: Related: [How do I fetch just the beginning of a Web page with LWP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984127/how-do-i-fetch-just-the-beginning-of-a-web-page-with-lwp)

Comment: @Cupidvogel I edited your query to better reflect your desire to match the sequence `cooler`.

Comment: i am planning to do this in Perl, parsing the web-page to find out the link, utilizing something like gunzip to extract the file, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read *some* of the file before downloading it?

You could use curl with its --range option to download part of the file.  But you'd need to know enough about the file to skip any meta/header data I assume.

`man curl`

note, according to the man page:

> You should also be aware that many
>   HTTP/1.1 servers do not have this feature enabled, so that when you
>   attempt to get a range, you'll instead get the whole document.

Comment: What I want to do is like this: the link is to a zipped file which contains a text file inside (no headers, just raw text). I want to unzip the zipped file, read first few lines from the extracted text file on the fly, and based on some result from comparing that text to some other text, I may download it or not. Is it possible?

Comment: @Cupidvogel - Zipped? No. Partial zips break.

Comment: No no, I don't want to unzip it partially. I want to unzip it fully, but without downloading it until the criteria matches. Much like when I am parsing a HTML page through **BeautifulSoup** without actually downloading the page...

Comment: If you could unzip an archive without downloading it, why do you think someone would be required to download the archive?

Comment: You can't unzip a file without downloading it first.  Also, archive files compress in a way that makes it so that it might not be helpful to try and download just some of the archive and attempt to extract the beginning of a text file within it.

Comment: Oh, then I guess I will have to download it! Right, I didn't think about it...Thanks.

Comment: @Cupidvogel - Are you confusing "downloading" (the process of transferring data from a remote machine to the machine the code is running on) with "saving downloaded data to a local file"? If so, then you can use LPW to download data and hold it in memory (where you can perform operations on it) without saving it to your disk.

Comment: Yeah, but that won't save the bandwidth, so it won't be much useful. What I wanted to do is check first and download afterwards. Since that cannot be done, I won't be better off if LWP stores it in memory and disposes it automatically if the check returns false...